# Text Mining in R - Remove Rows from Text File Starting With Keywords

Tags: r, pdf, text-mining

I am reading a text file into R like the following:

```
test<-readLines("D:/AAPL MSFT Earnings Calls/Test/Test.txt")
```

This file was converted from a PDF and retains some header data that I want to get rid of. They will start with words like "Page," "Market Cap," and so forth.

How do I delete out all rows beginning these keywords in my TXT file? This is as opposed to deleting rows containing that word.

---

Using one of the answers below I modified a bit to read in a

```
setwd("C:/Users/George/Google Drive/PhD/Strategic agility/Source Data/Peripherals Earnings Calls 2016")
text1<-readLines("test.txt")
text

library(purrr)
library(stringr)
text1 <- "foo
Page, bar
baz
Market Cap, qux"
text1 <- readLines(con = textConnection(file))
ignore_patterns <- c("^Page,", "^Market\\s+Cap,")
text1 %>% discard(~ any(str_detect(.x, ignore_patterns)))

text1
```

Here is the output I get:

```
> text1
[1] "foo"             "Page, bar"       "baz"             "Market Cap, qux"
```

What are the foo/baz/qux characters? Thank you

Comment: `grepl("^(Page|Market Cap)", df$id)` use to subset the rows. replace with your keywords. and `id` with your first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# once you have read and stored in a data.frame
# perform below subsetting :
x = grepl("^(Page|Market Cap)", df$id) # where df is you data.frame and 'id' is your 
                                       # column name that has those unwanted keywords
df <- df[!x,]  # does the job!
```

`^` helps to check the start. So if row starts with either `Page` or(`|`)`Market Cap` then `grepl` return `TRUE`

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. Can you refer me to a source that would help me transform the text file into a data frame? The text files will be unstructured call transcripts. This looks like a good solution but I am such an R rookie that I need remedial training! Thank you.

Comment: use `read.table` for details type `?read.table` in the R console. @GeorgeM

Comment: hey @GeorgeM hope you got it right with your real data!

Comment: I did. Moving right along. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
file <- "foo
Page, bar
baz
Market Cap, qux"
test <- readLines(con = textConnection(file))
ignore_patterns <- c("^Page,", "^Market\\s+Cap,")
test %>% discard(~ any(str_detect(.x, ignore_patterns)))
```

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong. My code/output pasted at the top. Ideally when I print the result I should basically see my text file stripped with the lines containing Page and Market Cap correct? Thanks for your patience, I am new at this (obviously).

Comment: Have you installed `purrr` and `stringr` first with `install.packages(c("purrr", "stringr"))` without errors? (Check output of `install.packages(...`